# Delete all active geofence on activity close

Tags: android, google-maps, android-geofence

I am trying to delete all active geofences when my activity.

Here is the code I am using :

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceService.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        //Setup permissions for location.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    },
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE
            );
        } else {
            if (lm != null)
                lm.removeUpdates(this);
        }
        if (allRequestIds.size() != 0) {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    allRequestIds
            );
            allRequestIds.clear();
            filterMap.clear();
            registeredFences.clear();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

I also tried :

```
if (allRequestIds.size() != 0) {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            );
            allRequestIds.clear();
            filterMap.clear();
            registeredFences.clear();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Unable to destroy activity, GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

The same thing is happening if I do it at onStop() method.

The end result being, the geofences that are added during previous runs are being kept. I don't want that. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems clear your `GoogleApiClient` isn't connected.

Try wrapping your statement in a `if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())`. Then if it's returning false I'd be looking around my code for where I've stopped it i.e. `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()`.

Note that `onDestroy()` is called when the `Activity` is *being* destroyed so it may be that the GoogleApiClient has already been disconnected by the system. (though I also note you say you have tried it in `onStop()`)